# Recent 12.04 update causes boot failure

Tags: 12.04, boot, updates

A June 03 2013 routine update of my system appears to be causing my Ubuntu 12.04 to no longer boot.  I've tried installing the binary Nvidia drivers,  since this has caused problems for me before,  but it appears to have another source.

Here is my boot.log  from /var/log .  The process actually hangs wherein I am forced to reboot.  I'm guessing it hangs somewhere after the VMware stuff fails.  I have no idea why it needs to launch VMware during boot.

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda3: clean, 996914/5373952 files, 9550102/21484929 blocks
modem-manager[953]: <info>  ModemManager (version 0.5.2.0) starting...
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Gobi
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Nokia
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Wavecom
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Option
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin AnyData
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Generic
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin MotoC
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin ZTE
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Sierra
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Option High-Speed
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin X22X
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Samsung
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Huawei
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Linktop
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Longcheer
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin SimTech
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Novatel
modem-manager[953]: <info>  Loaded plugin Ericsson MBM
 * Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Userspace bootsplash[74G[ OK ]
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
 * Starting AppArmor profiles       [128G 
[122G[ OK ]
 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting GNOME Display Manager[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting anac(h)ronistic cron[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting ACPI daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping GNOME Display Manager[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting crash report submission daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting automatic crash report generation[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting regular background program processing daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting deferred execution scheduler[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping anac(h)ronistic cron[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor[71Gfailed
   Virtual machine communication interface[71Gfailed
   VM communication interface socket family[71Gfailed
   Blocking file system[71G done
   Virtual ethernet[71Gfailed
   VMware Authentication Daemon[71G done
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
Raising maximum number of filedescriptors (ulimit -n) to 32768.
Starting tor daemon: tor...
Jun 03 20:14:33.272 [notice] Tor v0.2.2.35 (git-73ff13ab3cc9570d). This is experimental software. Do not rely on it for strong anonymity. (Running on Linux x86_64)
Jun 03 20:14:33.272 [notice] Initialized libevent version 2.0.16-stable using method epoll. Good.
Jun 03 20:14:33.272 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jun 03 20:14:33.273 [notice] Opening Control listener on /var/run/tor/control
done.
 * Starting the Winbind daemon winbind       [128G 
[122G[ OK ]
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned

apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
 * Starting web server apache2       [128G 
[122G[ OK ]
 * Starting anac(h)ronistic cron[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping anac(h)ronistic cron[74G[ OK ]
 * Checking battery state...       [128G 
[122G[ OK ]
 * Stopping System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting CUPS printing spooler/server[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting NetBIOS name server[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Mount network filesystems[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount network filesystems[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting emergency keypress handling[74G[ OK ]
acpid: exiting

 * Stopping Bridge socket events into upstart[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping SMB/CIFS File Server[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping OpenSSH server[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping system logging daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping ACPI daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping CPU interrupts balancing daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping regular background program processing daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping deferred execution scheduler[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping NetBIOS name server[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping automatic crash report generation[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Initialize or finalize resolvconf[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping emergency keypress handling[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting save system clock to hardware clock[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting save sound card(s') mixer state(s)[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping save sound card(s') mixer state(s)[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping save system clock to hardware clock[74G[ OK ]
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon[71G done
   VM communication interface socket family * Stopping device node and kernel event manager[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Bridge udev events into upstart[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping crash report submission daemon[74G[ OK ]
[71G done
   Virtual machine communication interface[71G done
   Virtual machine monitor[71G done
   Blocking file system * Starting emergency keypress handling[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping emergency keypress handling[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting save system clock to hardware clock[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting store software rfkill state[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting save sound card(s') mixer state(s)[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping store software rfkill state[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping save sound card(s') mixer state(s)[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting emergency keypress handling[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping emergency keypress handling[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting store software rfkill state[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting save sound card(s') mixer state(s)[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping store software rfkill state[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting emergency keypress handling[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping emergency keypress handling[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting store software rfkill state[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping store software rfkill state[74G[ OK ]
[71G done
 * Starting emergency keypress handling[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping emergency keypress handling[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting store software rfkill state[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping store software rfkill state[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping save sound card(s') mixer state(s)[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting emergency keypress handling[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping emergency keypress handling[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting store software rfkill state[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting save sound card(s') mixer state(s)[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping store software rfkill state[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping save sound card(s') mixer state(s)[74G[ OK ]
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
 * Stopping CUPS printing spooler/server[74G[ OK ]
 ... waiting  * Stopping save system clock to hardware clock[74G[ OK ]
. * Stopping web server apache2       [128G 
[122G[ OK ]
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
Stopping tor daemon: tor.
 * Stopping the Winbind daemon winbind       [128G 
[122G[ OK ]
 [33m*[39;49m   No VPN is running.
Checking for running unattended-upgrades: 
 * Asking all remaining processes to terminate...       [128G 
[122G[ OK ]
 * All processes ended within 2 seconds....       [128G 
[122G[ OK ]
 * Stopping bluetooth daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping mDNS/DNS-SD daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping network connection manager[74G[ OK ]
nm-dispatcher.action: Caught signal 15, shutting down...

modem-manager[953]: <info>  Caught signal 15, shutting down...
 * Deconfiguring network interfaces...       [128G 
[122G[ OK ]
 * Deactivating swap...       [128G 
[122G[ OK ]
mount: / is busy
 * Will now restart
```

Comment: Something seems to be causing Upstart to loop through jobs again and again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue...
I was told to check the permissions of the hidden file named .Xauthority placed in /home/your_username .

If the permissions is owned by the root you cannot log in to your system and you get stuck in the boot session.

Use the  chown command to change the permissions in order to be the owner of Xauthority and you should be able to log in.